# control panel login redirects back to login

Tags: control-panel, redirect, login, htaccess

First, I just took over administration of our Craft site from a previous employee, and the original site was set up by a contractor, so I'm still trying to figure things out.

Yesterday it was reported that people can't log into the control panel anymore.  The login page loads, you enter your creds, and it just brings you right back to the login page, no errors.  We've tried entering an invalid password, and then we do get an error message, so it's checking something.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I feel like I have inherited a mess where the Craft site is running in Azure as a web instance along with the MySQL, but some assets are coming from AWS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anything useful error messages in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`? If you open your browser's inspector's network tab, what's the response to the AJAX request that attempts to log in?

Comment: Also look for weird [redirects stuffed in .htaccess](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4880/1016). That's an easy 2 liner that will prevent anyone from logging in and would evade most logs.  That's kind of an easy way to cause the company some grief without breaking anything...

Comment: I had this today after setting up a new Homestead PHP7 box. The error from the AJAX request was about write permissions to /var/lib/php/sessions ( session_regenerate_id() was failing due to this ) Changing the permissions (to 0777 in my case) on that folder allowed the login.

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this, @Bryan?